# Symfony3 - Update multiple entities in single sql query

Tags: php, symfony

Bouncing from [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764029/symfony-update-multiple-records) i am looking for a way to update several Symfony entites in one sql query - for optimisation reasons. I have a Content entity, and a method in a service, that updates all "sibling" contents with setCurrent(0). Here's the working code so far:

```
/**
 * Set given content the latest regarding its siblings
 */
public function setLatestContent(Entity\Content $content)
{
    // Get siblings entities
    $siblings = $this
        ->em
        ->getRepository('LPFrontRteBundle:Content')
        ->findBySibling($content);

    foreach ($siblings as $sibling_content) {
        $sibling_content->setCurrent(0);
    }

    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Well that works. But since i have 38 sibling contents, i get 38 SQL queries like:

```
UPDATE mr_content SET current = 0 WHERE id = 55
UPDATE mr_content SET current = 0 WHERE id = 56
UPDATE mr_content SET current = 0 WHERE id = 57
...
```

I would like to use Doctrine's "clean" Entity system, in a way to have one query like:

```
UPDATE mr_content SET current = 0 WHERE id = 55 OR id = 56 OR id = 57 ...
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve that - or a smarter workaround, would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

For the record, here's what i came up with - i like it verbose :)
With $qb as query builder.

```
    $qb->update('LPFrontRteBundle:Content', 'c')
        ->set('c.current', 0)

        ->where('c.keyword = :keyword')
        ->setParameter('keyword', $content->getKeyword())

        ->andWhere('c.locale = :locale')
        ->setParameter('locale', $content->getLocale())

        ->andWhere('c.id != :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $content->getId())

        ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Batch processing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-updates) is what you're looking for.

There are two bulk update methods in Doctrine2.

First one is DQL Update Query, which will best probably best for you. It would be something like:

```
$q = $em->createQuery("UPDATE LPFrontRteBundle:Content c SET c.current = 0 WHERE id IN (:ids)")
        ->setParameter(':ids', $ids, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY));
$numUpdated = $q->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally went with a very close solution that i will post, but this is indeed what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can gather all ids and execute DQL to update all entities at once

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($siblings as $sibling_content) {
    $ids[] = $sibling_content->getId();
}

$this->em->createQuery("
    UPDATE
        LPFrontRteBundle:Content t
    SET
        t.current = 0
    WHERE
        t.id IN (:ids)
")
->setParameter(':ids', $ids, \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! What i did was skipping the "entities fetching" part to directly update from query. I read Repos are for "fetching" purpose only, but maybe it's only a philosophical matter?

Comment: I think that you are right and and some service is more applicable for so operations. In my project I place so operations in repository for simplicity :) I'll delete 2-nd part of my answer not to confuse other users